# what is the meaning of ##family

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I am looking at the folloing socket api code in sockaddr.h where it has a define as

```
#define  __SOCKADDR_COMMON(sa_prefix) \   
sa_family_t sa_prefix##family
```

How does this #define works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`##` is the macro token concatenation (or [*token pasting*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y.aspx)) operator in C.

---

That means

```
#define __SOCKADDR_COMMON(sa_prefix) \
sa_family_t sa_prefix family

__SOCKADDR_COMMON(foo);
```

would expand to

```
sa_family_t foo family
```

which would cause a compilation error, instead of correctly expanding to

```
sa_family_t foofamily
```

without it.

---

Why do you **need** the `##` operator, though? Simple; you can't do `sa_prefixfamily`, because that becomes a macro token itself (an undefined one, at that).

Comment: Well, if you say it's only about `##`, then it's a duplicate. Marked it.

Comment: @Deduplicator I would agree. :)

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

With `__SOCKADDR_COMMON(sa_prefix)` `#define`d the way it is,

`__SOCKADDR_COMMON(foo)` expands to the string `sa_family_t foofamily`.